# How to write hostfile in Slurm script

Tags: perl, slurm, sbatch

Currently I am doing following

```
 #!/bin/bash -l
 #SBATCH --nodes=2
 #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4

 scontrol show hostname $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST | perl -ne 'chomb; print "$_" x4' > myhostfile
```

This generates the following myhostfile

```
 compute-0
 compute-0
 compute-0
 compute-0
 compute-1
 compute-1
 compute-1
 compute-1
```

I would like  to have the following outcome

```
 compute-0
 compute-1
 compute-0
 compute-1
 compute-0
 compute-1
 compute-0
 compute-1
```

So that we alternate between all specified nodes

Comment: `chomb` is not a perl function, did you mean `chomp` ? Also `print "$_" x_4` is a syntax error

Comment: Corrected then syntax error.  I am using `chomb;`

Comment: There is no `comb` either. There's `chomp` to remove linebreaks from the end of a string, and `chop` to remove the last character from a string. Neither makes sense here though because you want the linebreak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ perl -e 'print +(<>) x 4'
```

This removes the `-n` loop from your code, and instead reads the entire `STDIN` in one go. We need the parentheses `()` to get the read operator into list context, so it reads all lines at once. The `+` tells the perl interpreter that the parentheses are a list, and not part of the `print` (as `print()`). Finally the repeat operator `x` in list context repeats the entire list.

```
$ cat foo
0
1
$ cat foo | perl -e 'print +(<>) x 4'
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
```